# Adduser command missing

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-stretch, sudo

I use **rkhunter** on all of my RPis, since some are used as dedicated servers, to try and ensure no rootkits or other malware are installed on them. When I did the check as usual today, I got the following error message one one of three Pis:

```
nat@PiVPN:~ $ sudo rkhunter -c
Invalid SCRIPTWHITELIST configuration option: Non-existent pathname: /usr/sbin/adduser
```

Concerned by this, I tried to run the adduser command, both with sudo and as the actual root user and got this error:

```
root@PiVPN:/home/nat# adduser foo
bash: adduser: command not found
```

Should I be concerned by this, and how am I able to re-install or find this command?

**System Information:**
Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1

**OS Information:**
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)
Release:        9.8
Codename:       stretch

Many Thanks,
Nathaniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Foundation's documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md) make it sound that `adduser` should be present on a recent Raspbian:

> **Create a new user**
>
> You can create additional users on your Raspbian installation with the `adduser` command.
>
> Enter `sudo adduser bob` and you'll be prompted for a password for the new user bob. Leave this blank if you don't want a password.

If it is missing for whatever reason (though I would wonder why that is) you can try to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install adduser
```

Comment: Thanks @Ghanima, I tried this already and it said that adduser was already the newest version so nothing was installed and the problem persisted. However after a reboot the issue was resolved. Not sure what the cause was but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your path was screwed up. Make sure /usr/sbin is in your path. I have it set in my root user's .bashrc